# Put 2 decimal places in textbox when it has whole number

Tags: jquery

Is it possible for text box when you enter whole number it will automatically add 2 decimal places?

Here is the script:

```
$('input[name^="txt1"], input[name^="txt2"], #qty').css('text-align','right').on("keyup", calculate);

function calculate()
{
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $('table.order-list tr input[name^="txt1"]:enabled').closest('tr').each(function ()
        {
        var row = $(this);
        var qty = +$('#qty').val();
            if(isNaN(qty)){
                qty=0;
            }
        var teo = +row.find('input[name^="txt1"]').val();
            if(isNaN(teo)){
                teo=0;
            }
        var tep = +row.find('input[name^="txt2"]').val();
        if(isNaN(tep)){
                tep=0;
            }
        var totalTime = (teo + (qty * tep)).toFixed(2);
        grandTotal += +totalTime;
        row.find('input[name^="total"]').css('text-align','right').val(totalTime);
        });
        });
}
```

Comment: Yep it is bro. `:)` It is possible. Share some code and we will fix it.

Comment: Yes. Now go try for yourself!

Comment: Eventhough I have onkeyup function like this one $('input[name^="txt1"], input[name^="txt2"], #qty').css('text-align','right').on("keyup", calculate);?

Comment: by "add 2 decimal places" do you mean adding ".00" to the number? so 100 becomes 100.00?

Comment: @SamBattat yap..that's it..

Answer (score 0):

Handle the blur event on your input like so...

```
$('#mytextbox').blur(function(){
    var t = $(this);
    t.val(parseInt(t.val()).toFixed(2));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dqrhz/1/

Comment: I add your sample code here: var teo = +row.find('input[name^="txt1"]').val(); like this one: var teo = +row.find('input[name^="txt1"]').val(parseInt(row.val()).toFixed(2));
   if(isNaN(teo)){
       teo=0; 
   }   but its not working.

Comment: all you should have to do with your above code is change totalTime to totalTime.toFixed(2)